# In Bolt CMS, What Permissions Do I Need to Set To Ensure Only The Owner Can Edit a Content Type?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm trying to set up a custom content type in Bolt so that only the owner can edit their own record. i.e. to stop users editing each other's records.

I don't seem to be able to get the right combination of permissions in permissions.yml though.

Using:

```
contenttypes:
    mycustomcontenttypes:
        edit: [ owner ]
```

in the content-type-specific permissions lists all of the mycustomcontenttypes on the overview page when I'm logged in as an account that owns a subset of the records, but none of the records I own have the title wrapped in a link leading to the edit page and the "Actions" menu does not have the "edit" option.

I would have expected the "owner" role to exist in order to give owners permissions relating only to their own records - surely that's the point of that role?

Is it therefore possible to set my custom content type such that (outside of superusers like root, admin etc) only the owner can edit their content record?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Try adding `view: [ owner ]` as well

Comment: @maiorano84 - I had the same idea, but that lists nothing at all. Doesn't even display the content type under "Content" on the dashboard. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I think [this](https://docs.bolt.cm/permissions#example-editors-and-chief-editors) might be close to what you want. Start with that, and then play with it until you get it to where you need.